# Create a NIB file for a popover view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am certain that I am missing something very obvious, but...

I want to create a XIB file that contains a view controller (with its embedded view) for display in a popup.  Create the XIB itself is not a problem, but sizing it is: Since it assumes it is a top-level view, it insists that it be full screen size, rather than the reduced size of a popover.

Is there a way of doing this, or am I stuck with creating the controller and view programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable all simulated user interface elements for the view in interface builder - status bar, navigation bar etc. Interface builder does not let you resize a view with those present.

Comment: You can also delete the original view, add a new one and connected to File's Owner.

Answer (score 0):

set the popOver view size using `setPopoverContentSize` .. this will changes the size of the popover’s content view .. for ex.

```
[aPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 300) animated:YES];
```